# How to prevent Puppeteer from focussing browse-window when it performs an action

Tags: google-chrome, puppeteer

I have puppeteer running in non-headless mode and I take screenshots every second. The problem is that I cannot do something else while it is doing this. Every time it takes a screenshot it brings the browser to the front. Is there a way to prevent this behaviour, so I can do something else in an other window for example. As I'm using chrome extensions I have to run it non-headless. But having the browser also makes debugging easier too.

Comment: you cannot do this in headful mode: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2656. there were workarounds that worked on macOS but since then it has been impossible to put headful chrome into background on any system.

Comment: Thats too bad, thanks!